# How to connect wires to this connector

Tags: connector

I need to connect this sensor to a breadboard. The device is a Gravity: I2C Digital Wattmeter from DFROBOT. The datasheet says this connector is a 3P Terminal. How do I connect my wires to this connector?

[image]

Comment: May be searching for "wire a terminal block" will help. First loosen the screws.

Comment: what do you see when you examine the connector?

Answer (score 4):

Strip wire end to the recommended length. If stranded wire, you may want to tin the wire end. [edit] When tinning, only the very tip of the wire.
Stick wire end in to the terminal (horizontal entry).
Tighten the recessed screw (vertical hole) with a LGS (little green screwdriver).
You may need to loosen the screw, however, fresh from the factory, you shouldn't need to loosen the set screw.

If you remove the wire, loosen the screw and pull the wire out. You may need to reset the metal contact before sticking the wire in again. Use a pithing needle tool, or equivalent, to reset the metal contacts.

Comment: In general that is the procedure. But the details contain bad advice. The wire should not be left bare and should not be tinned. There is a risk of bad connection and loose wires. The proper way is to crimp on a ferrule to terminate the wire before inserting it to the screw terminal.

Comment: Tinned stranded wire may deform over time and become loose. A more reliable approach for stranded wire is to use a ferrule.

Comment: Both comments are correct. If you only tin the very tip of the wire (takes practice), it prevents fraying when inserting the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a video that shows you how. The audio is not in English, but the video is self explanatory. Loosen screw in the recessed vertical hole, insert stripped end of wire into the horizontal connector/wire slot, and tighten vertical screw.

https://youtu.be/sBP-QrV5QSI